# database error:Unknown column 'michi' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, pdf

el nombre michi es un usuario registrado en mi bd. El codigo hace que me genere un pdf, hace rato estaba probando con una consulta mas sencilla y si me mostraba el pdf pero lo que quiero lograr es que me genere el pdf de la compra del usuario que obviamente acaba de hacer la compra en ese momento, todo esta en una misma tabla de orders pero lei que agregandole un AS tal vez se solucionaria y como el username tambien aparece el la tabla de customers los puse con un AS pero aun persiste mi error, espero y me puedan ayudar a modificar mi consulta o que me den alguna otra idea.

```
 <?php
  session_start(); //si esta logeado
  include "fpdf.php"; //LIBRERIA
  require 'connection.php'; //agrege
  $conn = Connect();
  $name =htmlentities( $_SESSION['login_user2'],ENT_QUOTES,'utf-8');  
  $sql = "SELECT c.username, o.foodname, o.quantity, o.price FROM customer AS c, orders AS o WHERE 
  c.username = {$name}";
   //o tambien
   //$sql = "SELECT username, foodname, quantity, price FROM orders WHERE username = 
   //{$_SESSION['login_user2']}";
  $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
  $pdf = new FPDF();
  $pdf->AddPage();
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
  while ($field_info = mysqli_fetch_field($resultset)) {
  $pdf->Cell(47,12,$field_info->name,1);
  }
  while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset)) {
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
  $pdf->Ln();
  foreach($rows as $column) {
  $pdf->Cell(47,12,$column,1);
  }
  }
  $pdf->Output();
  ?>
```

Comment: Te faltan unas comillas simples en el `WHERE` :)

Comment: ¿Puedes hacer un echo $sql y mostrar la salida? Para ver qué todo esté en orden en ese campo

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS DAVID JP, si eran las comillas simples. Saludos!!!